# component issue

Tags: visualforce-component

I have an component which will display all opportunity records created today and whose amount is greater than 50000.

I am not able to see any data when I preview the visualforce page.

**controller code:**

```
public String accID{get;set;}
public List<Opportunity> oppList{get;set;}
public List<Opportunity> getoppList()
   {
     if (oppList == NULL)
     {
      accID=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ID');
       oppList=[select Name,Account.Name,StageName,Amount,CloseDate from 
                Opportunity 
                where 
                AccountID=:accID;
                AND 
                Amount >= 50000
                LIMIT 10000];
     }
  return oppList;
    }
```

**The component is as follows:**

```
<apex:component controller="acctTemplate"
                access="global">

  <apex:attribute assignTo="{!accID}"
                  name="AccountID"
                  description="ID of the Account"
                  type="String"/>
<apex:repeat value="{!oppList}" 
                     var="opp">
        <tr>
            <td>{!opp.Name}</td>
             <td>{!opp.Account.Name}</td> 
</apexrepeat>
```

**I am calling this component inside as visualforce page as follows:**

```
<apex:page sidebar="false">
  <c:opptylist></c:opptylist>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

issue here 2 variable with same name i.e. oppList  and getoppList. both variable can access in vf using `{!oppList }` that's the issue.

below code should fix the issue

```
public String accID{get;set;}

public List<Opportunity> getoppList()
{
      accID=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ID');
      return Database.Query('select Name,Account.Name,StageName,Amount,CloseDate from'+
                            ' Opportunity  where AccountID=:accID '+
                            ' AND Amount >= 50000 LIMIT 10000 ');
}
```

### OR

```
private List<Opportunity> lstOpp;
public List<Opportunity> getoppList()
{
     if (lstOpp== NULL)
     {
       accID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ID');
       lstOpp = [select Name,Account.Name,StageName,Amount,CloseDate from 
                        Opportunity 
                        where 
                        AccountID=:accID;
                        AND 
                        Amount >= 50000
                        LIMIT 10000];
     }
     return lstOpp;
 }
```

Comment: Close enough, but there's no need for the temporary variable-- or it should be global so you only query once.

Comment: @ratan, I made the changes,its not working either way. Under an account, I created a few opportunity records and then preview the vf page but no data is displayed. am I doing right thing?Also I removed the where condition , but not working.

Comment: @PoojaBiswas can you pls add updated code in your question?

Comment: @Ratan,Is it permitted if I move the discussion to a chat?

Comment: @PoojaBiswas no you don't hv much reputation for chat

Comment: public String accID{get;set;}
private List<Opportunity> lstopp;
public List<Opportunity> oppList{get;set;}
public List<Opportunity> getoppList()
   {
     if (lstopp==NULL)
     {
   accID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ID');
      lstOpp = [select Name,Account.Name,StageName,Amount,CloseDate      from Opportunity  where 
                        AccountID=:accID
                        AND 
                        Amount >= 50000
                        LIMIT 10000];   
         }
      return lstopp;    I have not made any changes to component

Comment: @PoojaBiswas add debug logs and check.. code looks good

Comment: @PoojaBiswas any updates here?